# Using lambdas in template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to use a template class with a lambda function parameter. However, I don't understand how to pass the parameter. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class F>
class A {
public:

   int f(int i)
   {
       return F(i); //*
   }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
auto f = [](int i){return i+5;};
A<decltype(f)> a;
cout << a.f(5);
return 0;
}
```

I get an error in the marked line.

Can someone help?

Comment: Does the type `F` is needed in the class of only for method `f`?

Comment: only the method

Comment: F is a type (`class F`), what is the meaning of `F(i)` then?

Comment: static operator (works at c#)

Comment: Lambdas may be stateful (carrying captures). Your "static method" approach doesn't make much sense in light of this.

Answer (score 9):

Your example doesn't work because `F` is a type, not a callable object. The next step is to instantiate it by creating a member variable.

```
template <class F>
class A {
    F function;
public:
    int f(int i) {
         return function(i);
    }
};
```

However, that still won't work because lambda default constructors are deleted. That means we need another way to construct `function`. That can be achieved by passing an argument to `A`'s constructor.

```
template<typename F>
class A {
    F function;
public:
    A(const F& f) : function(f) {}
    int f(int i) {
        return function(i);
    }
};

// ...

auto f = [](int i) { return i+5; };
A<decltype(f)> a(f);
```

This uses the lambda copy constructor, which isn't deleted.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2af4f35c3118d134)

If you want it to work with any lambda, you can add some more magic.

```
template<typename F>
class A {
    F function;

public:
    A(const F& f) : function(f) {}

    template<typename ...Args>
    auto f(Args... args) -> std::result_of_t<F(Args...)> {
        return function(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bc19707feaa5a23)

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use template in order to accept *any kind of function's signature*, then the implementation should be something similar to this:

```
class A {
 public:
  template<typename F, typename... Args>
  auto f(F&& funct, Args&&... args) {
    return funct(std::forward<Args...>(args)...);
  }
};
```

That because you've said in the comment:

> Q: Does the type `F` is needed in the class of only for method `f`? 
>   A: *only the method*.

Because of that, it should be useless to have a template class, when you can just have a template method.

An here, an example how to call the method which just invoke the *"callable object with its parameters"*, in this case a lambda function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  A a;
  a.f([](int i) -> int { return i + 5; }, 12);
  //  |------callable object-----------|   |argument of function|
  return 0;
}
```

Practically, the method `f` accepts as first argument a "*callable object*" and as further arguments any parameters requested in order to invoke the first argument.

---

### Additional Notes:

If you want to pass to method `f` a certain type of signature of function,  for example: `int (*)(int)`, then you can avoid using template and pass an object of type `std::function`.

This is just an example:

```
#include <functional>
class A {
 public:
  // method g accept a function which get a integer and return an integer as well.
  int g(std::function<int(int)> funct, int arg) {
    return funct(arg);
  }
};
```

Comment: _Because of that, it should be useless to have a template class, when you can just have a template method._ A template method requires the caller to push in the lambda each time. A template class, as an example combined with type-erasure, can hide the actual lambda behind an `operator()`.

Comment: @skypjack That's the reason I ask whether he needed template only for method or a class. If the question were more clear about the purpose of the *generic* class `A`, it would be more easy to answer with a specific solution

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough to define `A` as inherited from or somehow containing a lambda function, you still have to initialize the subobject when you create an instance of `A`.
To do that, as an example, you can inherit from the lambda and use `A` as a callable object.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class F>
class A: public F {
public:
    A(F f): F(f) {}
};

int main() {
    auto f = [](int i){return i+5;};
    A<decltype(f)> a{f};
    cout << a(5);
    return 0;
}
```

You don't have to define any function `f` to *execute* the lambda.
Anyway, if you want to have a function `f` to be called as `a.f(5)`, you can define it as it follows:

```
int f(int i) {
    return F::operator()(i);
}
```

Or as it follows:

```
int f(int i) {
    return (*this)(i);
}
```